# regex - 4 digit number match and replace

Tags: regex

I want to match and replace a number of four digit numbers in a csv file

```
1,1456,2,3,4,5
2,1455,2,3,4,5
```

so that all 1400 numbers in the second column are mapped to the range of two hundred

```
1456 -> 256
1455 -> 255
```

I have this regex to match the 1400 numbers

```
',[1][4][0-9][0-9],'
```

but how can i define the matched substring regex to retain the last two digits of the match?

EDIT

Ended up changing the match regex to

```
,[1][4]([0-9][0-9])
```

and the match defined as

```
,2\1
```

in Notepad++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `/14(\d{2})/` with `2\1`, where `\1` is a back reference to the first match. Adapt to your regex flavor of choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/,[1][4]\([0-9][0-9]\),/,2\1,/'
```

Notice how the \( \) syntax captures a part of the matched expression, and \1 is used to say "the first captured data".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) - by surrounding one or more parts of a regex in parentheses, you can later reference them in the output. Here is my final version (works with sed -r).

```
's/,[1][4]([0-9][0-9])/,2\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a group, i.e. something like

```
',[1][4]([0-9][0-9]),'
```

Some regex dialects will let you name groups, e.g. in .NET

```
',[1][4](?<LastTwoDigits>[0-9][0-9]),'
```

If you specify which language you are using, it will be easier to help you.